# C++ NOVICE. Wierd Grader attempt at exception catch??? How to appease Grader?

Tags: c++, exception

I am doing some summer practice and got stuck on this challenge. The goal was to create a simple setItem() function. If testSetItem() function ran without exception, then the challenge was passed.

Here's the code. Idk how to throw the range_error exception to appease the test function.

When I submit this, the grader says:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::range_error: helpme

My Attempt:

```
void Vec::setItem(unsigned index, const Item &it) {
    if(index==0 || index > mySize)
        throw std::range_error("helpme");
    myArray[index] = it;
}
```

The grader code:

```
void VecTester::testSetItem() const {
    cout << "Testing setItem()... " << flush;
    // empty case
    Vec v0;
    try {
        v0.setItem(0, 11);
        cerr << "setItem() succeeded on empty Vec";
        exit(1);
    } catch (range_error&) {       <--------HOW DO I APPEASE THIS???
        cout << " 0 " << flush;
    }
    // nonempty case, valid subscript
    Vec v(5);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        v.setItem(i, i+1);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        assert( v.myArray[i] == (i+1) );
    }
    cout << " 1 " << flush;
    // nonempty case, invalid subscript
    Vec v2(3);
    try {
        v2.setItem(3, 33);
        cerr << "setItem() succeeded beyond end of Vec";
        exit(1);
    } catch (range_error&) {
        cout << " 2 " << flush;
    }
    cout << "Passed!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have calls to `setItem` that a) are outside the `try` block, and b) will throw. The uncaught exception is likely coming from those calls. In particular, `for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) { v.setItem(i, i+1); }` will definitely throw on the first iteration of the loop, when `i == 0`. Note that arrays in C++ are typically indexed starting from 0, not 1.

Comment: There are places you are calling `setItem`, while not in a `try`-`catch` block: `v.setItem(i, i+1);`

Comment: WOW. I am dumb. Thank you guys. I had to also make sure that the dynamic myArray was NULL.